# CiviMail link to view in browser gets error on mobile

Tags: civimail

End users received a mailing today, our first one on 4.6.3.

Desktop and laptop clients can follow the link, but tablets and cells get errors that the link can't be opened.

Link appears to add email or inbox before the url on those clients.

Worked up until the current version.  No changes to header template.

When you click on the link on Android devices they get:

Webpage not available
The webpage at email://18975 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Suggestions:
•   Make sure you have a data connection
•   Reload this webpage later
•   Check the address you entered

On IPhone, the link acts as if nothing's been clicked.

When you click on the link on Windows phone you get:
This link can't be open from an email message.
Link looks like: **inbox:"correct url"** (with quotes)

Links not in the header template work appropriately.

Comment: could you copy paste the relevant html par of your mailing -or at least the link?

Comment: Added some more details above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect the reason is because of [CRM-16549](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16549).  Please update to CiviCRM 4.6.4 and try again?